# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() - php

Tags: php, database, mysqli, error-handling

I have a base.php file that do config database

```
define("HOST", "localhost");            // The host you want to connect to. 
define("USER", "user");             // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "pass");     // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "base");  

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    echo('error do not connected to database'); 
}
```

and any other page that will connect to base.php for use database like this:

```
<?php 

    include '../../Connections/base.php';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";
            //  echo $query;
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['contain'];   
        }
    }   
    else
    {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }

?>
```

It doing work in localhost with XAMMP software and can find Base.php path and receive data from database but when i upload it in my website it get me

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() error

I copy Base.php codes instead of `((include '../../Connections/base.php';))` code . it do work in website but it's not safe and of course i have a lot of file that i should copy Base.php codes on there

how can fix that? Thank you

Comment: Note that the relative path used in xampp is not the same as the relative path on a "real" server. In xampp the root directory is htdocs. In contrast a live server root directory is the directory of your website. Try removing one set of `../` from your `include '../../Connections/base.php` then see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the relative path used in xampp is not the same as the relative path on an Internet web server.

In xampp the root directory is htdocs. In contrast an Internet server's root directory is the directory of your website.

Try removing one set of `../` from your include `../../Connections/base.php`.

Comment: i changed that before, i removed one set of ../ and two of them but don't work too

Comment: Remember to check your spelling, especially upper/lower cases. Is the base.php file actually on the server where you say it is?

Comment: Thank you @Kuya yes problem was for upper and lower case